# Move a range used in a function after a specific number of rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, array, range

I have a formula that is referencing a range. I want this range to move down one row every 20 rows as I copy the formula down. That is to say, the range needs to be the same for 20 rows, then move down one row. I managed to do it but I'm sure my way is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: So, how did you manage to do it? What is the unnecessarily complex formula you want to improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

=OFFSET($G$1,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/20),0,20)). I'm happy with that.

The first range will be G1:G20, then after twenty rows it will shift to G2:G21, and so on.